# Is overloading functions like $(document).ready bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jquery, but I know a few things and there's something intriguing me because I don't know if this is a bad thing to do or not. Is it bad to make use of `$(document).ready` for example or repeat the same function multiple times like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Button-1").click(function(){
        $(".contente-1").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Button-2").click(function(){
        $(".contente-2").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // another code here
});
```

Can this create conflicts, make the website slower or have a bad behave for the script? or this is the right way to do it?

I know I could do this in one single button or `$(document).ready` instead of creating two functions, but what I'm trying to understand is if it's bad repeating them many times like this

Comment: Bind is outdated, using multiple ready bindings is okay (but if you can avoid it, there's no point in having a number of them), this is a duplicate of countless questions.

Comment: What's the replacement for $(window).bind("load", function()

Comment: You'll find the answer if you take the moment to look at the manpage for bind.

Comment: is it `.on` the replacement for `.bind`? like `$(window).on("load", function()` I was trying to make some code load later or lazy load as described in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/run-javascript-only-after-entire-page-has-loaded/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't overloading. It is merely adding multiple handlers for a single event, which is perfectly fine.

jQuery will just execute all the `ready` handlers when the event occurs, or if it already has, it will execute the function straight away.

Comment: Thanks GregL! this clarifies my question

Comment: How in the lord did this get accepted, and mine got downvoted twice?

Comment: @wilsonhobbs You were downvoted either prior to editing your answer to be identical to mine, or because your answer is now identical to mine.

Comment: weird, I don't see why I would copy your answer, nor do I recall doing so, but it was 2 years ago so I don't know. I've taken my answer down